# jquery select menu select option is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is my code when i select one option, is get selected. when i go to next page and come back to same page the selected value is not appear.

```
$("#purpose-of").selectmenu({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if ($('#purpose-of option:selected').val() != 0) {
            $('.purpose-of-row').find('.error-message').hide();
            $('.purpose-of-row').find('.form-inner-field').removeClass('addRed');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please paste your html code too it is helpfull to get absolute answer

Comment: <select data-placeholder="Please select purpose of loan" id="purpose-of" class="select-drop-down">
            <option value="">Please select purpose of loan</option>
            <option value="Car purchase or repair">Car purchase or repair</option>
            <option value="Home improvements">Home improvements</option>

           </select>

Comment: How are you going to the next page? Sounds like you are navigating away without storing or keeping track of the value.

Comment: there will be one button with page link @majita

Comment: @achu this is not the right way to paste your code into comment you can update your question

Comment: @achu if you navigate to another page then you loose the state of current page. You need to maintain this value in some cookies or localStorage and when ever you come to this page run a script that will read from the storage and change the select element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of state i.e. store the value if you are going to navigate away. There are various ways to do this:

- Send the data to server and store in session or database etc.
- [Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
- [localStorage or sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Here is a code sample of how you could handle this using sessionStorage:

```
$("#purpose-of").selectmenu({
  select: function(event, ui) {
    if ($('#purpose-of option:selected').val() != 0) {
     //Save value for later use
      sessionStorage.setItem("purpose-of", $(this).val());
      $('.purpose-of-row').find('.error-message').hide();
      $('.purpose-of-row').find('.form-inner-field').removeClass('addRed');
    }
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Check when the page loads if value is stored and assign it to control if available
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("purpose-of")) {  
    $('#purpose-of').val(sessionStorage.getItem("purpose-of"));
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fu0vosf3/) - press run to simulate navigation